# Mail merging to multiple text boxes Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, textbox, office-interop, mailmerge

I have a template Word document which contains multiple text boxes on top of shapes (to give it a better border outline than what can be achieved my the outline of a text box). These text boxes contain mail merge fields that I wish to merge to. I have the following code in an attempt to do this

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range in document.StoryRanges)
        {
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Field field in range.Fields)
            {
                if (field.Code.Text.Contains("Test Field"))
                {
                    field.Select();
                    application.Selection.TypeText("test");
            }
        }
```

The problem is this only changes the fields within the first text box, I have searched both on here and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us) for a solution, however I am still having trouble actually finding a solution. I have also added the following lines in an attempt to figure out something

```
Console.WriteLine(document.StoryRanges.Count);
```

And within the foreach loop I also have

```
Console.WriteLine(range.Fields.Count);
```

The first call to WriteLine indicates there are two StoryRanges, one being the main document, the other being the range that all the text boxes are on, I presume. However, the second WriteLine indicates the first range has 0 fields, whereas the second range only has 1 field, even though the template document I am using contains over 10 fields.

Answer (score 0):

Are the StoryRanges nested ? Are they of different type?

If so, you should consider using StoryRange.NextStoryRange as proposed here:
http://word.mvps.org/faqs/customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm

```
'Iterate through all story types in the current document 
    For Each  rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges 

      'Iterate through all linked stories 

      Do 

      With   rngStory.Find 

        .Text =   "find text" 

          .Replacement.Text =  "I'm found" 

          .Wrap = wdFindContinue 

        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll  

        End With 

        'Get next linked story (if any) 

        Set  rngStory = rngStory.NextStoryRange 

      Loop Until  rngStory  Is Nothing 

  Next
```